# Ubuntu Mate LTS 14.04 boot menu will not load OS

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, mate

I am running ubuntu Mate 14.04 Lts and just recently I have not been able to boot with the grub boot manager. When I hit enter to load ubuntu, my screen freezes at the boot menu. I am able to login by booting in recovery mode and then pressing resume. I am worried that my boot menu will not work and would appreciate any help in finding out why this is happening and how I can get my system stable again.

Comment: I'd recommend trying `sudo update-grub` after logging in and see if that does anything. Are all of your partitions bootable?

Comment: The update-grub did not work.  I thought all my partitions were bootable but since a software update (which on restart was the initial incidence of the problem)  I have discoverd a new and separate ubuntu boot option that I cannot account for. It may be that this happened before the update as the failure following the update is what caused me to examine my bios settings. Also when I use boot repair it says that my boot files are far from the start of the partition and may not be recognized by the bios. It also advises a new partition with their relocation to the front.

Comment: I was initially wary of a new partition but it has started to seem that the partition is the source of the problem as to the boot-repair message and the mysterious partition. I uploaded all my recent changes to my programs and files to external storage as soon as I realized I could bypass grub via recovery mode. Am not looking forward to re-installing all my software packages and re-configuring my desktop and compilers. Thank god for shell scripting though...

Comment: this is my boot-repair url http://paste.ubuntu.com/10964708/

Comment: What was updating when it rebooted? Try running sudo sudo apt-get upgrade and then a dpkg-reconfigure command, as it might be a package that's causing the issue

Comment: linux-headers, linux-image-generic-LTs-utopic, curl, xserver, libcurl3, linux-generic-lts-utopic, linux-libc-dev,